# split string with number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like `"1)test one 2)test two 3)test three 4)test four 5)test five"`

I want result like below

> 1)test one
>   2)test two
>   3)test three
>   4)test four
>   5)test five

Split with "number + )" using jquery

Comment: @Keith: I upvoted Archer because he was spot on, it is so predictable that with a question like this people seem to throw the rules out the window because it suits them to get some easy rep. If the answer was not so simple, people would complain that no effort is shown. So why is it OK to only apply the rules when the questions take more than 30 seconds to answer? It makes the rules meaningless (in my opinion). Also, that article talks about being a community, well I personally don't want a community of people who want everything done for them, so I have no interest in helping them join it

Comment: Then you get the admin who think they can just delete your comments... they are the nicest of all the SO community... (there was nothing at all wrong with my first comment and it was well placed on this question to inform the OP of what they have done wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split by whitespace if exists and take a positive lookahead for number/s and closing parenthesis.

```js
var string =  "1)test one 2)test two 3)test three 4)test four 5)test five";

console.log(string.split(/\s*(?=\d+\))/));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"1)test one 2)test two 3)test three 4)test four 5)test five".split(/\b(?=\d+\))/gi)
.join("\n")

"1)test one 
2)test two 
3)test three 
4)test four 
5)test five"
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should add an explanation to your answers, not just drop code.

Comment: Does every solution need an inline explanation? isn't the intent clear?..

Comment: Reasons this answer is bad. 1) it's just a block of code 2) the formatting is wrong 3) most importantly, you are creating a single string result. Op mentioned multiple times they want to **split**... though it must be said the question could be a lot clearer on this!

Comment: he used the world split, but his desired output is nowhere close to it. So you acknowledge that the question is not clear yourself. No need to discuss further. Not gonna argue for a downvote.

Comment: @ibowankenobi: What do you mean desired output is nowhere near it? The output is clearly a list of 5 different items.